# CSS top margin of div

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a website and I have some problems with margin.

I have a following HTML code:

```
<div id="mainBody">
    <div class="subTitle" id="backgroundTitle" >
        <h3>
            Background
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

my CSS code is the following:

```
#mainBody{
    height:200px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}


.subTitle {
    margin-top=0px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}


h3 {
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

the result I'm expecting is that the "mainBody" div has 0px top margin while the h3 inside has 100px top margin. However, what I got instead is that the "mainBody" div shifts down with h3 together, meaning that they both have a top-margin of 100px with respect to the top of the page.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Adjoining margins: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

Comment: Thanks! @CBroe, this cleared my confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display:inline-block;` to h3 element class.

```
h3 {
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/366Vb/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem! See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KLD2U/). I added borders to the elements to clearly see the element position.

Note:I have tested in FF 26.0, Chrome 32.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

This is how it looks:

[image]

I added borders to see the element boundaries:

```
#mainBody{
    ...
    border:1px solid red;
}

.subTitle {
    ...
    border:1px solid green;
}


h3 {
    ...
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: _“I added borders to see the element boundaries”_ – and by that, you switched the effect of adjoining margins off …

Comment: Wow! My bad ... Wait a minute .. then we can use invisible borders to switch off this effect when we don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

During the workflow, You will  need  to remove collapsing, for that you probably need this http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure you really need the `<h3>` - you could just style the text in the subtitle.

CSS

```
#mainBody{
    height:200px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.subTitle {
    margin-top=0px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 70px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 6px solid red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="mainBody">
    <div class="subTitle" id="backgroundTitle" >
      Background
    </div>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/Luy7a/)